# Changing the Lead OwnerId upon clicking on a confirmation email link after submitting a cloud page form

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, record-owner

I have a custom HTML form on the cloud page whereupon submitting I am creating a lead in sales cloud using CreateSalesforceObject() function.
Now I want that After the Lead has completed the form they should receive a confirmation email to their provided Email. IF they click the link to confirm, the Lead owner should update OwnerId.
What is the best possible way to achieve this?
Should I go with workflow or process builder? if yes then how should I approach?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is what happens:

1. A Lead enters a CloudPage, they fill out the form and submit
2. On submission, a Salesforce Lead is created and at this point, you want to trigger an email? If yes, you can do so by using a Triggered Send. You place the script right after the `CreateSalesforceObject()` function and use the Lead ID returned from the `CreateSalesforceObject()` function as the SubscriberKey. Here is a script snippet and an article explaining how to [trigger an email using AMPscript](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/29/send-a-triggered-email-using-ampscript/):

```ampscript
/* create a new lead */
SET @leadId = CreateSalesforceObject(
      "Lead", 4,
      "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),
      "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname"),
      "Company", RequestParameter("company"),
      "Email", RequestParameter("email")
     )       
       
/* send a confirmation email */
SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")
SET @ts_extkey = "43099" /* TS external key */
SET @ts_email = RequestParameter("email")

SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", @ts_extkey)
SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)
 
SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", @ts_email)
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @leadId)

AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_sub)

SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)
```

3. In the email that gets triggered, create a button that will lead to another CloudPage
4. On that new CloudPage, you can include the `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject()` function to update the Lead owner and display some kind of a Thank you message to the end user:

```ampscript
/* update existing lead */
SET @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
    "Lead", _subscriberkey,
    "OwnderId", "newLeadOwnerId"
   )
Output(v("Thank you for confirming your email."))
```

This solution is all done in SFMC without the need to include any additional processes in Salesforce.

Comment: Thank you so much mate, it worked pretty well. Also i wanted to let you know that i have created a triggered email and in the email template, i have attached the link for a cloud page saying 'thank you' and AMPscript for UpdateSingleSalesforceObject() function is not working as the ownerId is not being updated. Kindly let me know if there is anything i am missing.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: CreateSalesforceObject and triggered email is working fine and the emails are being delivered smooth. I have now created a cloud page and added the ampscript similar to what you have mentioned. my query is that how are we fecthing the @leadId via cloud page AMPscript?

Comment: I've updated my answer (the code for the update function) - you can use a personalization string `_subscriberkey` to fetch the Id, you just need to use the CloudPagesURL function to redirect from email to CloupdPage: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5

Comment: Do i need to pass subscriberkey as a parameter in CloudPagesURL function?. Because upon clicking, it's not redirecting

Comment: No, it will be done automatically - please read this: https://ampscript.guide/cloudpagesurl/

Comment: Are you sure the UpdateSingleSalesforceObject is correct for updating the ownerId?. On clicking the confirmation button, the created lead is disappeared and when i tried to search the lead with the previous lead Id, it's giving this error. "Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details. The requested resource does not exist". What else are we missing here?